# What will be ActiveX name and type of firebreath plugin?

Tags: javascript, activex, firebreath, ieaddon

I am trying to access a firebreath plugin from js using new ActiveXObject(servername.typename) ?

I am not sure if I am feeding the correct name , I interpreted 
servername as by plugin name
&
typename as pluginNameAPI class name .

When trying to create an ActiveXObject using this naming convention I get error "Automation server can't create object".

Comment: Richard Replied on mail: 
the string you're looking for is in PluginConfig.cmake as ACTIVEX_PROGID

Comment: I see that ACTIVEX_PROGID comes with $ sign in cmake, is this a variable being set during prepmake, or can I define any hard coded value here. 

Can I define hardcoded value in this format servername.typename ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my older FireBreath project the ActiveX Object name is taken from these params in PluginConfig.cmake (separated with dot):

- COMPANY_NAME
- PLUGIN_NAME

So I can instantiate the plugin with

```
o = new ActiveXObject("MyCompany.MyPlugin");
```